# Gson.fromJson stuck on line

Tags: javascript, java, json, server, gson

I'm using gson to parse data coming in from an HttpExchange object. However, in my IDE I set a breakpoint at the line where I use `.fromjson` , and it never moves past that line. It just comes back to it again and again.

```
public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("/createTest");
        if (exchange.getRequestMethod().toLowerCase().equals("post")){
            System.out.println("get request");

            InputStream reqBody = exchange.getRequestBody();
            String reqData = readString(reqBody);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            TestRequest testRequest = new TestRequest();
            System.out.println(reqData);
            testRequest = gson.fromJson(reqData, TestRequest.class);
            System.out.println("gson done");

            //Get the test
            TestService testService = new TestService();
            TestResponse result = testService.execute(testRequest);}
```

Here's the updated java for TestRequest.java

```
import Model.TestParameter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestRequest {
private HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, book> sections;
private int difficulty;
private boolean closedBook;
private int length;
private int assortment;
```

I used JSONlint to check that the JSON data I was feeding it was correct, and it was. Here it is, for the curious:

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "chapters": [
        11,
        12,
        20,
        21,
        22
      ],
      "book": "NEPHI1"
    },
    {
      "chapters": [
        20,
        29
      ],
      "book": "NEPHI2"
    },
    {
      "chapters": [
        1
      ],
      "book": "OMNI"
    }
  ],
  "difficulty": 3,
  "closedBook": true,
  "length": 21,
  "assortment": 0
}
```

Comment: How does it behave when you run in non-debug mode?

Comment: It throws an exception (I should have been doing try/catch). This is the exception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 15 path $.sections[0]

Comment: Can you update the question with source code of `TestRequest`?

Comment: Done! You can see it in the original post

Comment: What is the type of `TestParameter.book`? It looks like `sections` according to java model should be map of  `TestParameter.book` and `List` but your json has string `"book": "NEPHI1",`. Try changing this json snippet to `"book": ["NEPHI1"],`

Comment: The JSON object holds data of books and chapters within the books. There could be many books in the object, but the array is of book/chapter array pairs. This is why the object is formatted this way. Have I done it wrong? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I've updated with a better example for the JSON object being passed

Answer (score 1):

> ```java
> private HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, book> sections;
> ```

Gson thinks your `sections` field is supposed to be a map...

> ```
> "sections": [
> ```

...but instead you have an array of items, each of which is an object with `chapters` (an array of integers) and `book` (a String). `Map` and `HashMap` take two generic arguments, where the first is a key and the second is a value. In JSON, the key will almost always be a `String`, like in this JSON representing a `HashMap<String, Integer>`:

```
{
  "abc": 123,
  "def": 456
}
```

If you want to match the JSON you've provided, you'll need `sections` to look something like this:

```java
public class Section {
  private ArrayList<Integer> chapters;
  private String book;
}
private ArrayList<Section> sections;
```

---

> However, in my IDE I set a breakpoint at the line where I use `.fromjson`, and it never moves past that line.

It sounds like you understand `try`/`catch` in the comments, but for your question title "stuck on line" and this quote in your question, I'll summarize here.

When something unexpected or erroneous happens in a Java application, (an "exception" as in your `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException`), it will look for the nearest enclosing `try`/`catch` block. If there isn't one in the current method, it will check the method that called the current method, and then the one that called *that* method, and so forth. Web server applications often have an enclosing `try`/`catch` that will result in an error code like 500, and if nothing catches the error at all it will likely terminate the program. You can learn more about Exceptions in the [Java tutorial "What is an Exception?"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html), but the appearance of it being "stuck" on that line is likely a result of it proceeding into a default exception handler and never returning to the method where the exception was "thrown".